# Update Online/Offline status in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am developing a chat app with React + AppSync + DynamoDB. I wanted to show the Online/Offline status to other **users** in the App. So I created a field called **isActive** in the **user** table. Whenever the user logs in to the app I change it to **Online**. When the user turns off the internet I need to update the status as **offline**. But this not happening, since I have disconnected from the internet the API call to update offline status is failing.

Comment: try using OnlineJS

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I google it. But I did not see any libraries as of now.

Comment: https://github.com/PixelsCommander/OnlineJS

Comment: Sorry. This is not what I needed. This code will just update the frontend. I need to update the backend as well when the user switches between online and offline. But in the specific case when the user goes offline, the API to update the status will fail since it cannot connect to internet

Comment: For your information, I am already able to detect online and offline status in frontend